# How to do groupby + insert + finding max(id) from table A and insert in records of table B

Tags: python, postgresql

I am trying to scrape data into Postgresql.
i have two tables :

1. Primary key(Id)
2. Foreign key(proj_id) (references Id from 1)

I am getting basic info into table 1 with autoincrement type.
For 2nd table the data is stored in the temp table and then insert operation on temp for table 2.
I am stuck how to add the primary key, tried with max(id) but it gets inserted only for one record in table 2 after grouping. But multiple records are avlb.
Attached queries.

```
#insert in table 1
inst_proj = """INSERT INTO tbl_project_new(Sr_id,Name_of_project,Project_type,Builder_Name,Rera_Last_Mod_Date,Proposed_Completion_Date,Project_Area,Sanctioned_Bldg_Count)
                    VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s) Returning Id """
```

```
#inserting in temp
inst_stmt = """INSERT INTO temp_data(sr_no,Project_name,Building_Name,Apartment_Type,Min_Area,Total_Apts,Booked_Apts)
                    VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s) """

#updating proj_id -> foreign key (this is giving errors as only last row is updated)
update_id = """UPDATE tbl_extract_apt_inventory_total SET proj_id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM tbl_project_new) WHERE id =( SELECT MAX(id) FROM tbl_extract_apt_inventory_total);"""
```

```
##inserting in table 2 after grouping operation on temp
inst_stmt2 = """INSERT INTO tbl_extract_apt_inventory_total(Project_name,Building_Name,Apartment_Type,Min_Area,Total_Apts,Booked_Apts) SELECT Project_name,Building_Name,Apartment_Type, MIN(Min_Area), SUM(Total_Apts),SUM(Booked_Apts) FROM temp_data GROUP BY Project_name,Building_Name,Apartment_Type"""
```

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of using an auto-increment primary key, could you generate your own primary key? If you did that, you wouldn't need to try to figure out what the primary key is afterward.

Comment: Actually there is no way for primary key, for that reason we need to autoincrement to keep track of records inserted